# What is the base source of the IP address lookup information?

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address

There are tools online where you can find info regarding any IP address.

If I type in my own IP I get my ISP name, somewhat accurate location etc.
Where is this data stored and how do these tools retrieve it (is there a public api/database?)? Is there some global datasource for this? Or is every ISP managing their own source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://whatismyipaddress.com/learning/ip-addresses) or [this](http://whatismyipaddress.com/learning/the-internet) might have your answer.

> Geolocation services have access to a number of databases (different
>   kinds) that give them the information needed to locate someone online
>   through their IP address. A primary source for IP address data is the
>   Regional Internet Registries. These are large, official organizations
>   responsible for managing and distributing IP addresses in specific
>   regions of the world. You can read more about RIRs here. The RIR for
>   North America is called the American Registry for Internet Numbers
>   (ARIN).